# Programmatically work with the Vim command mini-buffer

Tags: vim

I think my problem here may be that I don't have the correct terminology to search.  I want to write a plugin that is interactive in the little mini-buffer area (in Emacs terminology, sorry) at the bottom of the window, where your cursor is placed when you type <kbd>:</kbd> to enter command mode.  Plugins like FuzzyFinder and ctrlp seem to open a new buffer, but ideally I'd like to just share the command area, if that is possible, since what I want to do will always fit on a single line.

Does Vimscript allow this area to be used, much like Vim's own built-in wildmenu works?  Opening a new split buffer just feels kinda clunky for what I want to do.

Happy to do the reading of the documentation myself, I just don't really have an entry point at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

That's the command-line.

See [this Vim wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/User_input_from_a_script) about `input()`. What kind of things do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks.  Got as far as playing around with `getchar()`, though I may be heading down the wrong path. I'm looking to write my own take on fuzzy finding of files/buffers, partly for learning and partly because I don't like ctrlp/fuzzyfinder's approaches. Effectively once my function is started, each keypress in the command line will be read and the fuzzy search continued. Following the cursor, the best completion (in the current directory) will be selected, then the other matches following thereafter, truncated with `...`. Some other key mappings added once the basic idea is working.

Comment: What I'm failing to fathom out, is how to effectively rewrite what is in the command line after each key press (i.e. insert the fuzzy completions). I'm just reading lots of help pages at the moment :)